# Software to download FC2 videos on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, video, download-manager

[FC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC2_(portal)) is the third most popular video hosting service in Japan.

How to download videos from FC2?

Requirements:

- Runs on Linux (without WINE)
- Free, ideally open source

Comment: Is Firefox addon [Flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/flashgot/) ineffective?

Comment: Same question for the [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) Firefox addon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a command-line tool, [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) can handle FC2 links.

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/fc2.py

Use it like this:

```
youtube-dl http://video.fc2.com/en/content/20130725s9ppAvVC
```

Answer (score 2):

[Flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/flashgot/) can download FC2 videos.

Just install Flashgot go to the FC2 webpage, start playing, press Flashgot Media (1) and enter a filename and folder.

Thanks Firelord (and Izzy) for the tips, I had no idea non-specialized tools would work for such a particular website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/):

- freeware
- ads-free (make sure you uncheck/skip the spyware when installing JDownloader)
- standalone
- works with Windows/Linux/Mac
- can download FC2 videos
- tons of other features

[image]